# How to register my application on facebook

Tags: facebook

I cannot find URL where I can register my own web site or application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and you'll find the button "Create an application". You can then register an application. An OAuth key and an OAuth secret will be given by Facebook after registration.

Answer (score 3):

On Facebook there is an app called Developer that you can use. That app is used to manage the apps you have developed, so you can go there to add a new app.

Incidentally, this has nothing to do with OAuth (since you have that tag on this question.)

Comment: But if i want to get access to facebook api i must pass oAuth2.0 authentication, right? I need to have app_token for oAuth

Comment: That is correct. You don't need any special authentication to register an app, but you do need that authentication to make requests. You get the credentials after registering.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - [Register Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). Just click on the 'Create New App' button and away you go..

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/ and you will the detail facebook application information.You can thn register an application.